# Set new page as home page, keep current url

Tags: aspx, homepage

I created a page under SitePages that includes CEWPs and such. My current home page url is http://{mysite}/default.aspx. I want to make my new site the home page without changing the default url. I've tried copying my new page to the root folder where I would change the file name but it doesn't load, gives me a "Sorry, something went wrong" error. I've tried numerous things but nothing is working.

Is what I want to accomplish possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are working in SharePoint on - premises, and you have added some content in the page2 but you want still the original URL remain same.

So, instead of creating a new page, you can add a script editor web part in the original default.aspx page, inside that you can write your all new content.

With that being said, still we can change the site url. Create a **newpage**, and set that as home page from the site setting, now site url would be newpage.aspx.

After that run the below PowerShell command, and again change the URL back to the **Default.aspx**.

```
Set-SPSiteURL -Identity $site -Url http://mysites/default. aspx -Zone 0
```